# Error with Gradle in my first project with new Android Studio

Tags: android, compiler-errors, gradle, android-studio

I created my first project with Android Studio and I've got the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
[ 183260]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -  
[ 183267]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
[ 183267]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -  
[ 183268]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - * What went wrong: 
[ 183275]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Failed to notify model configuration listener. 
[ 183276]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - > No builders are available to build a model of type 'com.android.build.gradle.model.AndroidProject'. 
[ 183279]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -  
[ 183279]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - * Try: 
[ 183279]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Run with 
[ 183281]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with 
[ 183282]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - --info 
[ 183286]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - or --debug 
[ 183294]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - option to get more log output.
```

And in the IDE I've got "setContentView(R.layout.Main); Main cannot be resolved or is not a field"

And I don't find Class 'R'.

I look up by google and I did not find any solution that resolves my problem.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04, 64 bits.

Comment: I solved the problem by updating to version 0.1.8